# Changing an element at a particular array in ndaray

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, lemmatization

I have created a numpy array in python like `a = np.array([[2,3,4],[6,7,8]])`
Now I see there is a put function using which I can specify to modify 
a particular index value. I did `a.put([0,1],100)` But the resulting array got 
modified to 
array([[100, 100,   4],
[  6,   7,   8]]) 
The intention was to modify the value 3 to 100. How can I achieve this in python 
The normal index access fails when the array contains strings with 
message `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`
The use case for this is I am reading data from a file and I have 
to lemmatize or stem it for building model `numpy_array = df.to_numpy()`
X=numpy_array[:,1]
This X is what I have to lemmatize and I was using the approach

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X[i])):
         X[i][j]=lemmatizeSentence(X[i][j])
```

Which gave the above error

Comment: what about `a[0,1] = 100`?

Answer (score 0):

The value can be changed by direct assignment.

```
a = np.array([[2,3,4],[6,7,8]])
a[0,1] = 100
```

Comment: But that doesn't work for array with strings eg when I do  X[i][j]="xyz" I get the error `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Yes. In Python, strings don't support assignment